# приватный именованный параметр dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Я новичок в Dart. Допустим у меня есть `final List<Character> _characterList;` который должен быть private. Но как мне использовать  `CharacterList( {Key key, this._characterList}) : super(key: key);`  если именованный параметр не может начинаться с _ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть:

```
CharacterList({Key key, List<Character> characterList}) : _characterList = characterList, super(key: key);
```

либо:

```
CharacterList({Key key, List<Character> characterList}) : this._characterList = characterList, super(key: key);
```

Также можете производить вычисления/приведения и т.п. (не лучшая практика, но в определенных случаях удобно):

```
CharacterList({Key key, List<Character> characterList}) : _characterList = characterList.map(<Какие-то преобразования>).toList(), super(key: key);
```